# Embedding an OpenXML document within another OpenXml document

Tags: c#, openxml

I have a need to gather a number of .docx files in a folder and "chain" them into a single document that will be displayed to the user.

Now I've read [Brian Jones' article](http://blogs.msdn.com/brian_jones/archive/2009/06/30/embedding-an-open-xml-file-in-another-open-xml-file.aspx) but while it sounded promising I have encountered a problem.

When I perform the actions manually using Word 2007 I end up with a copy of the docx file in the /embeddings folder and when I open the document I am presented with the embedded content.

However, when I do the same thing through code I end up with a file called package.bin in the /embeddings folder and when I open the document I'm greeted with the alternate image telling me to Double-Click on it to activate the embedded document. This is not what I wanted.

Can someone clarify how I embed the document(s) so that they appear as .docx files rather than .bin? I'm hoping that this will overcome the Double-Click to Activate issue as well.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Be careful how you step!

http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/technology/8197990.stm

Comment: I'll deal with that as and when I have too ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I posted this question on the [OpenXMLDeveloper forums](http://openxmldeveloper.org/forums/thread/7369.aspx) and was directed to another [article by Brian Jones](http://blogs.msdn.com/brian_jones/archive/2008/12/08/the-easy-way-to-assemble-multiple-word-documents.aspx).

While the blog pointed me in the right direction it was not a magic bullet. I had issues with formatting that were resolved by adding a MatchSource element to the AltChunk;

```
MatchSource matchSrc = new MatchSource();
matchSrc.Val = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.BooleanValues.True;
altChunk.AppendChild(matchSrc);
```

I also needed to remove the footer from the documents being merged as they were being replicated in the new document (resulting in numerous footers within the main footer!). Now I just have the footer in the template for the master document.

Hope this helps someone else as there doesn't seem to be too much information out there are the moment.