# Cannot embed an openXML document inside another using OpenXML SDK

Tags: c#, .net, openxml

I'm trying to embed an OpenXML word document inside of another OpenXML word document and it's creating corrupted files. I've already review this post 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_jones/archive/2009/06/30/embedding-an-open-xml-file-in-another-open-xml-file.aspx and this stack overflow post [Embedding an OpenXML document within another OpenXml document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271056/embedding-an-openxml-document-within-another-openxml-document) and I think I'm following the instructions, but I'm not getting the same results.

My code looks something like this.

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, byte[]> docKV in files)
            {
                var embeddedPackagePart = document.MainDocumentPart.AddNewPart<EmbeddedPackagePart>("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", "rfp" + docKV.key);
                var stream = new MemoryStream(docKV.Value);
                embeddedPackagePart.FeedData(stream);
                stream.Close();
}
```

So essentially I'm looping through a list of files stored in a dictionary and embedding each file. I've removed the code that creates the actual OpenXML markup to link to the embedded object to try and narrow down the error. As far as I can tell the actual embedding is what creates the issue.

I've also opened the generated document using the OpenXML SDK Productivity tool, and it is missing the embeddings section that I see on documents where I manually embedded a file.

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. I was not calling WordprocessingDocument.Close before disposing of the WordprocessingDocument. If you are adding new document parts you have to invoke Close() for those to get written to the underlying stream.

Answer (score 0):

You can read [Merging word processing documents](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2008/10/27/how-to-use-altchunk-for-document-assembly.aspx). Sample code is available too.

Comment: That's not quite what I'm looking for. I don't want to combine the documents, instead I want to embed document B inside of Document A the same way that objects are embedded when you choose the "Insert --> Object" menu options.